# get Image to encoded path to set image is not working?

Tags: android

I am having  weird problem, I am having a user click button to choose an image. Then I am storing the encoded path in db and retreiving it later so I display the image in another activity but I am getting the following Exception

```
09-14 01:39:36.195: W/System.err(2241): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /external/images/media/1113
09-14 01:39:36.195: W/System.err(2241):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:610)
09-14 01:39:36.195: W/System.err(2241):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:542)
09-14 01:39:36.195: W/System.err(2241):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:377)
```

My button OnClick & store in db code:

```
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                InputStream imageStream;
                try {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inSampleSize = 8;
                    Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options );
                    ivPictureChosen.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                    storeEncodedImageInDb(selectedImage.getEncodedPath());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't pick image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

My retreival & showing image code:

```
            String imagePath = db.getEncodedImage();
            if(imagePath.length()>0){
                Uri mainImgeUri = Uri.parse(imagePath);
                InputStream imageStream;
                try {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(mainImgeUri);
                    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inSampleSize = 8;
                    Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options );
                    mainImage.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

How come the file is not found although thats the encoded path I got in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not only need the path but also scheme etc.
An Uri looks like so: http://www.stackoverflow.com or file://foo/bar/image.jpg.

encodedPath is only the path part of this, e.g. stackoverflow.com or /foo/bar/image.jpg.

Try to store the result of `yourUri.toString()` in the database and retrieve `Uri.parse(theStringFromDatabase)`

Comment: Ohh that makes sense. So if i need to store a uri in db which takes that as a string, what would be the best way? Currently I am using selected Image.getPath, but that is obviously wrog according to ur answer

Comment: See edited answer. I think you just can use the uri's `toString()` and later `parse` that string to get the Uri object again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that encode and decode it to `base64 string` and return from `base64 string`, please have a look.

```
public static String encodeTobase64(String Path)
{
    Bitmap immagex=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Path), 140, 120, false);    
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
    return imageEncoded;
}
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) 
{
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length); 
}
```